# The text in the Modal View Controller does not change in the view controller

Tags: ios, swift, view

I am a beginner in iOS.

I have a problem that I made a class named `ModalViewController`. To make this as a common class, I didn't give any text to the textView in this class. So I tried to change the text when I present this viewController.

But I am getting an error. How can I fix it?

In addition, how can I change the `margin` value in text view?

**Main.storyboard**

[image: storyboard]

**MainViewController.swift**

```swift
import UIKit

var modalview : ModalViewController!
class ViewController: UIViewController {
...
    @IBAction func Onclick(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalViewController")
        myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
        modalview.modalCustomAlert.text = "test test test text" // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**ModalViewController.swift**

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ModalViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var modalCustomAlert: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var okButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func cancelPress(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    @IBAction func okPress(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        modalCustomAlert.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    }

    @IBAction func modalbutton(_ sender: Any) {

    }
}
```

---

### Edited start

---

I tried to assign a value but there was no change in the error.

```swift
var modalview = ModalViewController()
...
    @IBAction func Onclick(_ sender: Any) {
        ...
        modalview.modalCustomAlert.text = "test test test text" // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

    }
```

---

### Edited TWO start

---

I've tried this already. But when I saw the answer from **@PGDev**, I tried it again, but it showed the same error.

```swift
    @IBAction func Onclick(_ sender: Any) {
        ...
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalViewController") as! ModalViewController
        myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        myAlert.modalCustomAlert.text = "test test test text" // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value**

```
modalview.modalCustomAlert.text = "test test test text"
```

The exception is because either `modalview` is `nil` or `modalCustomAlert` is `nil`.

**1.** You've created `modalview` as *implicitly unwrapped optional* like,

```
var modalview : ModalViewController!
```

Check if you've assigned any value to `modalview` before accessing it. If you haven't this will result in crash.

**2.** Next, you have created an `outlet` of `modalCustomAlert`,

```
@IBOutlet weak var modalCustomAlert: UITextView!
```

This is also an *implicitly unwrapped optional*. Check if the `outlet` is connected properly. If it isn't it will raise the runtime exception.

> If an implicitly unwrapped optional is nil and you try to access its
>   wrapped value, you’ll trigger a runtime error. The result is exactly
>   the same as if you place an exclamation mark after a normal optional
>   that doesn’t contain a value.

**Edit-1:**

```
var modalview = ModalViewController()
```

The above code won't connect the `outlets` in `ModalViewController`. That's the reason `modalCustomAlert` is `nil` and result in exception.

Create `modalview` using storyboard like,

```
let modalview = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalViewController")
```

One question though. What's the reason to create `modalview` and `myAlert` separately if they both are of type `ModalViewController`?

**Edit-2:**

I don't think there is even a need to create `modalview`. Simply use `myAlert` view at the line where you're getting the exception. So the code for `ViewController` goes like,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //....
    @IBAction func Onclick(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalViewController") as! ModalViewController
        myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        myAlert.modalCustomAlert.text = "test test test text"
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Edit-3:**

Got that. Just didn't realise that you're accessing modalCustomAlert before the outlets are created.

First of all, in `ModalViewController` create a property `text`. And in `viewDidLoad()` add this `text` as `modalCustomAlert.text`, i.e.

```
class ModalViewController : UIViewController {
    //rest of the code....
    var text: String? //here....

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        modalCustomAlert.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.modalCustomAlert.text = text //here....
    }
}
```

Now, when creating `alertView`, replace

```
myAlert.modalCustomAlert.text = "test test test text"
```

with

```
myAlert.text = "test test test text"
```

Comment: Hi @PGDev  `ModalCustomAlert` was created by me on the storyboard myself, then through the right-click button. This will not be nil.

Comment: `var modalview = ModalViewController()
var modalview : ModalViewController!`  is see error `Invalid redeclaration of 'modalview'`

Comment: I didn't assign a value to `modalview`. Isn't this how you use it? How should I use it?

Comment: because `myAlert.modalCustomAlert.text` is see error `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'modalCustomAlert'`

Comment: This is because you're not typecasting it to `ModalViewController`. See **Edit-2** in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. @PGDev  But this has already been tried. But I tried it again. But it showed the same error. Please look at my revised question.

Comment: Disconnect `modalCustomAlert` outlet and connect it again.

Comment: I erased and built the code for 'modalCustomAlert' and made it again through UClick on the storyboard. But the errors are the same.

Comment: Updated the code. See **Edit-3**. The code will work now.

Comment: Thank you really much @PGDev. It worked for me. Can you tell me why?

Comment: And I asked the question if you could adjust the Margin value. can you tell me how to adjust the value of MarginTop or MarginBottom?

Comment: Great. This is because the outlets will not be connected until after the `viewDidLoad()` of the controller is called.

Comment: Oh @PGDev  I'm understand. um..  Could you let me know if you know how to adjust the margin value of the text in the text view?

Answer (score 0):

Please add one new variable **String** in Your **ModalViewController**

```
class ModalViewController : UIViewController {

      var objTextViewString:String = ""

      override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()
              self.modalCustomAlert.text = self.objTextViewString
      }

}
```

On **ModelViewController** Present Please pass String On added String Variable..That's It..!!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //....
    @IBAction func Onclick(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalViewController") as! ModalViewController
        myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        myAlert.objTextViewString = "test test test test"
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```